# TypeError : storage.getItem() is not a function - node-persist module

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-persist

I'm using the node-persist module to persist some data. Have implemented the same using the below documentation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-persist/v/1.0.1

**Version - "node-persist": "^3.1.0"**

Below is my code

```
const storage = require('node-persist');
class NetworkClass {
  public getNetworkIdentity = async (): Promise<any> => {
          //My Business logic goes here
          // Here I receive the identity with its expiry
          await storage.init({ ttl: 3600 });
          await storage.setItem('networkIdentity', JSON.stringify({
                 identity: "XXXXX"
          }));
  }

  public getNetworkIdentity = async () => {
        let myIdentity = storage.getItem("networkIdentity")
        return myIdentity
  }
}
```

Using this I can see the file getting created inside a node-persist folder in my source structure, it also has value. But while fetching it using storage.getItem()

I'm getting the below exception :

**TypeError : storage.getItem() is not a function**

Also I'm facing one problem

After the completion of first request, even when storage.setItem() is done successfully, when the seconds request comes I see the persistent file being deleted already. And I don't find the data related to networkIdentity

**Updates:**
While iterating over multiple requests, I see that the persistent file is still there with the data that is set, but when I try to read it using `await storage.getItem()` or `await storage.data()` no data is being fetched and I get the exception again as storage.getItem() is not a function, although the storage file is still present.

Comment: When you setItem try to make it string :  `await storage.setItem('networkIdentity', JSON.stringfy({identity: "XXXXX"}));`  Try to check the storage object content does it include getItem method?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, yes have tried that, updated the question.
Below is the information showing in the file generated in node-persist directory

{"key":"networkIdentity","value":"{\"identity\":\"XXXXXXX_VALUE\"}","ttl":1652246547364}

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I see the persist file present in my source with the data, but when I try to read it using storage.getItem() or storage.data(), storage object don't show the stored values.

Comment: It seems you need to init it properly with the correct path.

Comment: The TTL getting saved is 
"ttl":1652265363816 even if I give the value 3600 during storage.init()